# Walllet is "locked". Can't pay transaction fees to close/update program

Tags: anchor, solana-program, metaplex, account, authority

I am currently facing this issue that doesnt let me close my program (I don't really want to loose all the rent right now)
https://forums.solana.com/t/help-me-my-wallet-was-locked-unable-to-pay-a-transaction-fee/7802

TLDR: My wallet is owned by the BPF upgradable loader and I can't do any transactions with it so it's kind of like a loophole because I can't change the owner if I can't pay the transaction fees.

here the steps in detail:

1. Program deployment failed
2. closed buffer account to reclaim funds
3. cannot create new buffer/update program authority because authority wallet's assigned program id is BPF upgradeable loader and therefore can not be used to pay for transaction fees.

Question: Is there a way to specify the fee payer to change the program authority?

Answer (score 2):

Every command with the `solana` CLI allows you to specify the fee payer, typically through the `--keypair` parameter.  So for example, to close a buffer, you can do:

```
solana --keypair <FEE_PAYER_KEYPAIR> program close <BUFFER_ID> --authority <CURRENT_UPGRADE_AUTHORITY_KEYPAIR>
```

Comment: The command we needed didn't have a fee payer argument built in so we wrote our own Script in rust using the code from the solana CLI with the addition of specifying a keypair

Comment: That's a fine addition too -- feel free to create a PR with that change!